# How to compile specific dependencies using maven

Tags: maven

I have a situation where in i need to clean and install couple of dependencies of my maven project. While I am working on this project i am making changes in these dependencies and have to manually clean and install for every small change i am making. I am trying to find a maven command which will make my life easy.

1. project-bpm-process <-- parent project
2. project-odata-service - < dependency >
3. project-core-service  - < dependency >

I cannot put them as sub modules as they are not really modules of my this project, they are simply dependencies. So, literally group-id does not match in complete sense (there is a partial match but does not help in any way).

**Update 1:**

Tried the option 2 suggested by Mark. I see below error which indicates that the sub modules (aggregated projects) are not found under the parent project's folder.

> [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the
>   POMs: [ERROR] Child module
>   E:\STS-Workspaces\default-workspace\project-bpm-process-artificial\project-core-service
>   of
>   E:\STS-Workspaces\default-workspace\project-bpm-process-artificial\pom.xml
>   does not exist @
>
> [ERROR] Child module
>   E:\STS-Workspaces\default-workspace\project-bpm-process-artificial\project-odata-service
>   of 
>   E:\STS-Workspaces\default-workspace\project-bpm-process-artificial\pom.xml
>   does not exist @
>
> [ERROR] Child module
>   E:\STS-Workspaces\default-workspace\project-bpm-process-artificial\project-bpm-process
>   of 
>   E:\STS-Workspaces\default-workspace\project-bpm-process-artificial\pom.xml
>   does not exist @

I just created a new maven project with packaging "pom" type and added other projects as modules. Now, "project-bpm-process-artificial" has become artificial parent of all the three projects I was talking about.

From [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation), i see that the path is relative.

**Update 2:**

Location of actual pom is located at: *E:\STS-Workspaces\default-workspace\project-bpm-process-artificial*

But other referenced projects are in *C:\Users\ramgo\git* **and** *E:\git-repos*. These projects are imported into eclipse for development.

The pom.xml is here:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-bpm-process-artificial</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>project-bpm-process-artificial</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <modules>
        <module>project-core-service</module>
        <module>project-odata-service</module>
        <module>project-bpm-process</module>
    </modules>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Solution:** For all practical reasons I found option 1 is easy to implement (option 1 provided by Marks). It hardly took 5 minutes to write a batch script. Here is the one for handy reference.

```
set core=<directory_path_of_core_project>
set module_one=<<directory_path_of_module_one>>
set module_two=<<directory_path_of_module_two>>


cd %core%
call mvn clean install


cd %module_one%
call mvn clean install


cd %module_two%
call mvn clean install
```

Option 2 seems interesting but not feasible in my case. Links don't work and no way to refer absolute path for sub modules.

.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notion of Maven dependency assumes that the artifact is build externally (not even necessarily with maven) and available to your project as a third-party jar.

So, the terminology in the question is misleading to me.
If you have some third-parties (I assume having their own pom.xml) but are external to your project, then obviously in your project you can't manage them. Maven can't build external stuff.

So, based on these assumptions, the choices are:

**Option 1**

Create a script that will:

- enter the dependency directory
- run mvn install on that directory
- enter your project's directory
- run mvn whatever on your project

**Option 2**

Create an "artificial" pom.xml that will have packaging type "pom" and will list both your project and the dependencies as submodules (your project and dependencies will be peers):

```
 |__some_folder
    |__pom.xml
    |__dependency1
    |  |__pom.xml
    |__dependency2
    |  |__pom.xml
    |__your-project
       |__pom.xml
```

In this case you will be able to operate with both your project sources like one project and you'll be able to use the following:

```
cd some_folder 
mvn clean install --projects <your-project> --also-make
```

So that if your project has dependencies in other modules, they'll also be built

I would probably go with the second option, but its your choice really

**Update 1**
Based on the information you've provided:

1. Don't really count on eclipse, its not really relevant at this point. You should try to get to the point where running maven from command line should work. The eclipse will follow your poms once you've done everything right.
2. If you place the "artificial" pom into `E:\STS-Workspaces\default-workspace\project-bpm-process-artificial` then all the modules should be in sub-folders:

```
     E:\
      |_ STS-Workspaces
         |_ default-workspace
           |_ project-bpm-processes-artificial
              |_ project-core-service
              |   |_pom.xml of that module
              |   |_.git // it can be a root of git repo
              |   |_src
              |_ project-odata-service
              |    ...
              |_ project-bpm-process
```

After that you can do the following to check yourself:

```
cd E:\STS-Workspaces\default-workspace\project-bpm-process-artificial
mvn clean install
```

It should compile all the libraries and your project 
Then if you want to build your project (assuming its called `project-bpm-process`) then you can do from the same folder:

```
mvn clean install --projects project-bpm-process --also-make
```

If it has a dependency on `project-core-service` but, say, not on `project-data-service` then only the `project-core-service` will be rebuilt

Now when the maven if sorted out, you can add eclipse workspace in any other folder. I can't comment much on eclipse since I'm an IntelliJ user. In intelliJ you can just import this artificial pom and it will automatically recognize all the projects. In eclipse I think it should work similarly

Comment: The magic word "artificial" sounds interesting. One hurdle is that all these projects (git repositories) are imported into eclipse workspace as maven projects. Their project directory is somewhere else. The "pom" project is looking for projects within workspace and is failing. I cannot use "parent" in these submodules as one of them already has spring-boot as parent.

Comment: You don't have to use inheritance (parent tag) only aggregation... you could import a single "artificial" module into eclipse and this can do the job. I'm not really familiar with eclipse though so cant comment much on this. BTW for spring boot you dont have to use inheritance, you can also import spring boot BOM for the same effect...

Comment: I have tried with just aggregation. Updated the question with what i tried. Let me know if you have any suggestions there.

Comment: Please post the "artificial" pom and where exactly it located in file system

Comment: Updated the question with pom and location details

Comment: Hi Mark, Do you have any other comments?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, not sure I’m following... have you tried the described approach? Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, i did. Please check my "Update 2" in the question. I followed 2nd approach and provided the pom.xml, project locations and error is already provided in "Update 1"

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed that update. Anyhow, i cannot bring them under artificial pom folder. Because when i import projects into eclipse it just maintains a reference to the git repository location and all updates are done to the same git folder. I hope, this is same with any other IDE. Do you have a solution to refer to the absolute path of the sub modules? I don't find that from maven documentation

Comment: How about links in filesystem?

Comment: Btw maybe you keep the sources themselves (with git repos and everything) as I've stated in the update 1 of the answer but the workspace could be in a different folder ( even different disk)